# How to make dragging faster using velocityView in UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer

Having a little trouble understanding how to implement a faster dragging speed for the code I'm using below (written by @PaulSoltz) which allows you to drag an object across the screen. I realize you have to use the `velocityInView` method from `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and I understand it returns the x velocity vector and y velocity vector. If velocity = distance over time, then for instance `velocityx = (x2 - x1) / time` and I'm unsure how to use this formula to get what I need. Basically I just want to be able to adjust the speed of my movement to make it a little faster. Maybe I'm over thinking things, but if anyone could help me understand this it would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    UIView *myView = [gestureRecognizer view];

    CGPoint translate = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[myView superview]];


    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [myView setCenter:CGPointMake(myView.center.x + translate.x, myView.center.y + translate.y)];
    [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[myView superview]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply the components of the translation vector by some constant.

```
[myView setCenter:CGPointMake(myView.center.x + translate.x * 2, myView.center.y + translate.y * 2)];
```

Comment: Ok so the velocityView keeps track of how fast or slow you drag the object, and if you want to just make it a constant speed for any kind of dragging, you just multiply by some constant? Makes sense...

Comment: This does the job, but it makes the image move faster than your finger over it, which makes it look funny. I don't actually think there is a way to make it move faster without doing this, since it's all based on your finger speed.